# ¿Como puedo obtener la información de dos tablas relacionadas en django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando hacer un queryset que me permita mostrar en mi HTML el nombre de  los ALUMNOS que participan en un proyecto.

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    es_alumno = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    es_profesor = models.BooleanField(default=false)

class Proyectos(models.Model):
    nomnbreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    fechaCreacionP = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    fechaModificacionP = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Usuarios')
```

mi view es el siguente:

```
@login_required()
def teacher_home(request):
    proyectos = Proyectos.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "home/teacher_home.html", {'Proyectos':proyectos})
```

Hasta aqui tengo lo que necesito, que es mostrar al maestro los proyectos en los que él esta involucrado pero cómo le puedo hacer para poder obtener la información de los alumnos que participan en el proyecto? por ejemplo mostrar al maestro sus proyectos (eso lo hace la query que tengo ahi) y tambien poder mostrar el first_name de los usuarios que tambien estan enlazados al proyecto?

ME REFIERO A MAESTRO por que mi view me redirige a un home dependiendo del tipo de usuario en este caso es el de maestro

Espero haber hecho bien la pregunta y espero me puedan apoyar.

**Actualizacion:**

Actualmente mi proyecto necesita mostrar los proyectos enlazados al ususario que tiene la sesion iniciada (ya esta resuleto ese punto)

[image: Los proyectos del usuario logueado]

necesito que en esa parte donde dice TEAMS MEMBER me muestre los first_name de **Usuarios**

de ese proyecto, en este caso que la relacion es de muchos a muchos necesito que se muestren los miembros (los miembros son los marcados en la siguente imagen)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no logro hacer que mi consulta me deje obtener campos de la tabla Usuarios y de la tabla Proyectos al mismo tiempo , no logro hacer esa relacion , mi html itera en proyectos para mostrarme los campos como {{ proyectos.id }} y me regresa el id del proyecto pero no puedo hacer que me muestre el last_name del Usuario "docente" , eso es lo que ando buscando

Comment: `request.user` que valor trae? en el query

Comment: En este caso es el nombre del usuaario logueado que le puse : docente1 , es para mostrar los proyectos en los que está el usuario que incia sesión pero quiero saber cómo hacer referencia al proyecto donde está el docente1 y que pueda mostrar el nombre de los usuarios relacionados

Comment: Y actualmente `{'Proyectos':proyectos}` que trae? podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que actualmente hace tu proyecto y un ejemplo de lo que esperas? creo que no queda muy claro.

Comment: @Sr1871 devuelve todos los campos de mi modelo proyectos que se filtran por el usuario logueado dándome solo la información de esos proyectos - ahora edito la pregunta con mas informacion.

Answer (score 0):

Existen posibles soluciones:
Manteniendo la estructura actual:
Iterar los valores proyecto.user en el template excluyendo el usuario actual.

```
{% for estudiante in proyecto.user %}
{% if not estudiante.id == request.user.id %}
{{ estudiante.get_full_name }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Otra opcion habilitar un boton para que el docente pueda ver el detalle del proyecto siempre tendrias que utilizar un codigo similar a parte de crear una nueva view para controlar la peticion de informacion.

Modificando un poco la estructura de tu codigo:

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    es_alumno = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    es_profesor = models.BooleanField(default=false)

class Proyectos(models.Model):
    nomnbreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    fechaCreacionP = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fechaModificacionP = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    encargado = models.ForiegnKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ParticipanteProyecto(models.Model):
    proyecto = models.ForiegnKey(Proyectos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participante = models.ForiegnKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="estudiantes")
```

La view la modificarias un poco

```
@login_required()
def teacher_home(request):
    proyectos = Proyectos.objects.filter(encargado=request.user)
    return render(request, "home/teacher_home.html", {'Proyectos':proyectos})
```

en el template utilizarias lo siguiente para enlistarlo

```
{% for estudiante in proyecto.estudiantes.all %}
{{ estudiante.get_full_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: muchas gracias lo probare enseguida y ¿es mas recomendable trabajar con una relación ManyToManyField o separarla como lo hiciste tú? gracias

Comment: depende el caso... pero te recomiendo de forma separada, asimismo, puedes revisar el tema de normalización de base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Logré hacer la relación con un simple

```
Participantes=Usuarios.objets.filter(proyectos__user=reques.user)
```

Esta forma de hacer la relación en las tablas me permite ir desde a tabla Usuarios hasta la de proyectos mostrando los datos que tenga relacionado el Request.user ( que es el usuario logueado ) y así nuestro solo lo que tiene que ver con mi user, tan fácil que era